# SignalR - Calling a WPF Client method from a Self-Hosted Console Server

Tags: c#, wpf, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I followed [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/804770/Implementing-SignalR-in-Desktop-Applications) tutorial and managed to set up a **Client -> Server** and **Server -> Client** realtime communication demo. However, when trying to recreate the same scenario in a WPF project (instead of a Console project), I can't seem to call the WPF Project's method from the SignalR Hub.

**NOTE:** The WPF Project and the Self-hosted Console Project are in the **same** Visual Studio Solution

**SignalR Hub:** (in the Self-host Server Console Project)

```
public class TestHub : Hub
{
    public void NotifyAdmin_Signup()
    {
        Clients.All.NotifyStation_Signup();
        //This should call the WPF Project's NotifyStation_Signup() method
    }
}
```

**Starting the Server & Calling the Hub method from the same Console:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Start the Local server
        string url = @"http://localhost:8080/";
        using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Server running at {0}", url));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        IHubContext hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<TestHub>();
        hubContext.Clients.All.NotifyAdmin_Signup();
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs in the WPF Project:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
         InitializeComponent();

         var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:8080/");
         IHubProxy _hub = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("TestHub");
         hubConnection.Start().Wait();

         //Call a local method when the Server sends a signal 
         _hub.On("NotifyStation_Signup", x => PrintAccountCount());
    }

    //This never gets called :(
    private void PrintAccountCount()
    {
         //Display a Message in the Window UI
         var dispatcher = Application.Current.Dispatcher;
         dispatcher.Invoke(() => counter_accounts.Content = "I got the signal!");
    }
}
```

There are **NO ERRORS**. The WPF Project's 'NotifyStation_Signup' method never gets called by the server. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it! I made a silly mistake by Calling the hub method outside of the using() method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Start the Local server
    string url = @"http://localhost:8080/";
    using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Server running at {0}", url));
        //Instead of having the following two lines outside of this, 
        //I put it in here and it worked :)
        IHubContext hubContext = 
                 GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<TestHub>();
        hubContext.Clients.All.NotifyAdmin_Signup();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try registering the event *before* you start the hub connection.

```
     var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:8080/");
     IHubProxy _hub = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("TestHub");

     //Call a local method when the Server sends a signal 
     _hub.On("NotifyStation_Signup", x => PrintAccountCount());

     hubConnection.Start().Wait();
```

Comment: Same result. Doesn't get called bro